# I can't send emails from a list of emails on a spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, outlook

So, what I need to do is: send e-mails to a list of e-mail that are on a spreadsheet. And I need to send them from Outlook.
I am really new at programming, actually, this the first time I try to program.

This is the code I have:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

# criar a integração com o outlook
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

# criar um email
email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

email_list = pd.read_excel('D:\Projeto Zurich/email_list.xlsx')
cliente = email_list['EMAIL']


# configurar as informações do seu e-mail
email.To = "cliente"
email.Subject = "Informações sobre o seu sinistro!"
email.HTMLBody = """
<p>Prezado(a) segurado(a),</p>
<p>Foram realizadas diversas tentativas de contato sem sucesso para agendar a realização da visita da assistência técnica Electrolux, por esse motivo estamos cancelando o seu sinistro.</p>
<p>Para solicitar a reabertura, você pode entrar em contato pelos nossos canais de atendimento:</p>
<p>4020 4848 (capitais e regiões metropolitanas)</p>
<p>0800 285 4141 (demais localidades)</p>
<p>Ou através dos nossos canais digitais em https://www.zurich.com.br/pt-br/atendimento</p>

<p>Atenciosamente,</p>
<p>Zurich Seguros</p>
"""

email.Send()
print("Email Enviado")
```

And this is the spreadsheet I have:

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

PS.: The code works when I am not trying to use the spreadsheet, like when I add a real email address at email.To =

Comment: `email.To = "cliente"` means that you're literally trying to send an email to the address `"cliente"`. Also, if that spreadsheet contains actual email addresses, I highly recommend you delete the image from here and instead provide fake examples instead, since that's personal info. Regardless, it looks like what you need to do is send an email to each index of `cliente`, meaning you need to loop through its items, and send an email to each item. Or, if you want to email a specific address, you need to specify the index, i.e. via `cliente[i]` where `i` is the index.

Comment: Do **NOT** post others' email addresses here.  Edited.

Comment: what is the result that you are giving?

Answer (score 1):

Clientele is a string. If you wanted to use clientele as a variable you'd have to delete the quotes around it. That being said I would overcome the problem with a simple for loop. It really depends on if you want to send one giant group email or if you want to send to the recipients individually. If you wanted to send it individually, the code could be updated as

```
for x in clientele:
     email.To = x
     email.Subject = "Informações sobre o seu sinistro!"
     email.HTMLBody = """
     <p>Prezado(a) segurado(a),</p>
     <p>Foram realizadas diversas tentativas de contato sem sucesso para agendar a 
 realização da visita da assistência técnica Electrolux, por esse motivo estamos 
 cancelando o seu sinistro.</p>
     <p>Para solicitar a reabertura, você pode entrar em contato pelos nossos canais de atendimento:</p>
     <p>4020 4848 (capitais e regiões metropolitanas)</p>
     <p>0800 285 4141 (demais localidades)</p>
     <p>Ou através dos nossos canais digitais em https://www.zurich.com.br/pt-br/atendimento</p>

     <p>Atenciosamente,</p>
     <p>Zurich Seguros</p>
"""

     email.Send()
     print("Email Enviado")
```

This will substitute the TO address with each individual's email and send them one at a time.